# Getting an error: object() takes no parameters in Python

Tags: python, class, methods, constructor, instance

I am getting **TypeError** says that **objects takes no parameter**.

I don't know what's wrong with my code. Can anyone help me to figure it out.

```
class Animal:

    def _init_(self, color):
        self.color = color
    
bingo = Animal("Brown")

print(bingo.color)
```

Comment: you need double underscores surrounding `__init__`

Comment: What a silly am I ? Thank yo so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are considering `_init_` method as the constructor of your `Animal` class. But, you need to put double underscores before and after your constructor like [this](https://pythonbasics.org/constructor/#toc2). The following code works fine:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

bingo = Animal("Brown")
print(bingo.color)
```

If you do not want to change the name of your `_init_` method, you need to call it differently like this:

```
class Animal:
    def _init_(self, color):
        self.color = color

bingo = Animal()
bingo._init_("Brown");
print(bingo.color)
```

This should also work fine.